# Passing variables to a constructor with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I am having problems passing up two pieces of data through my classes, ID and Name specificly. I understand that you cannot call the base class constructor up without going through the previous parent classes but I am struggiling to fiugure out why this is not working, do I need constructors all the way up or can I just add it on at the end of my class creation like the base class?

Thanks in advance.

```
class CEmployee
{
private:
char m_name[30];
char m_id[30];
//virtual float Pay() { return 0;};  // virtual function
virtual float Pay() = 0; // pure virtual function
public:

CEmployee(char name[], char id[])
{
    strcpy_s(m_name, name);
    strcpy_s(m_id, id);
}

CEmployee()
{
    strcpy_s(m_name, "");
    strcpy_s(m_id, "");
}
void PrintCheck()
{
    cout << m_name << "  " << Pay() << endl;
}
};

class CFulltimeEmployee : public CEmployee
{
protected:
static float m_benefitcost;
public:
CFulltimeEmployee()
{

}
CFulltimeEmployee(char name[], char id[]) : CEmployee (name, id)
{
    m_benefitcost = 100;
}

};

float CFulltimeEmployee::m_benefitcost = 100;

class CHourlyFTEmployee : public CFulltimeEmployee
{
private:
float m_rate;
float m_hours;
public:
CHourlyFTEmployee()
{
}

CHourlyFTEmployee(const char name[], const char id[], float rate, float hours) : CFulltimeEmployee 
(name, id)
{
    m_rate = rate;
    m_hours = hours;
}
float Pay()
{
    return m_rate * m_hours - m_benefitcost;
}
};
```

Errors

Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "CFulltimeEmployee::CFulltimeEmployee" matches the argument list

Error   C2664   'CFulltimeEmployee::CFulltimeEmployee(char [],char [])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char []' to 'char []'    Project9

Comment: What kind of problems do you have with the code you show? If you get build errors the please copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question.

Comment: In C++ you really, really should be using `std::string` and make every effort to avoid `char*`, *especially* situations where you have these absolutely minuscule buffers of size 29.

Comment: Just a point about terminology: this is not multiple inheritance. Multiple ineritance refers to a class having more then one **direct** base. `struct a {}; struct b {}; struct c : a, b {};`.

Comment: Don't delete your question's text with destructive editing; it doesn't help future readers. If you don't want to keep the question, mark it for deletion. Rolling back your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) really isn't that hard; you remove whatever isn't needed while still demonstrating the problem.  In this case, it might be:

```
class CEmployee
{
    char m_name[30];
    char m_id[30];
    virtual float Pay() = 0; // pure virtual function
public:
    CEmployee(char name[], char id[])
    {
        strcpy_s(m_name, name);
        strcpy_s(m_id, id);
    }
};

struct CFulltimeEmployee : public CEmployee
{
    CFulltimeEmployee(char name[], char id[]) : CEmployee(name, id) { }
};

struct CHourlyFTEmployee : public CFulltimeEmployee
{
    CHourlyFTEmployee(const char name[], const char id[]) : CFulltimeEmployee(name, id) { }
    float Pay() override { return 0.0; }
};
```

In particular, notice that none of `m_benefitcost`, `m_rate` or `m_hours` are needed; nor is `PrintCheck()`.  (`class` is `private` by default while `struct` is `public`; this also helps to reduce noise.)

Once you've done that, it's very easy to see the problem the compiler is complaining about

> error C2664: 'CFulltimeEmployee::CFulltimeEmployee(char [],char [])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char []' to 'char []'

In `CHourlyFTEmployee`, you've written **`const`** `char name[]` (and `const char id[]`); but the base class (`CFulltimeEmployee`) is `char name[]`—no `const`.  Data that is `const` can't "easily" be assigned to non-`const` data; the "fix" is straight-forward: remove the `const`:

```
CHourlyFTEmployee(char name[], char id[]) : CFulltimeEmployee(name, id) { }`
```

The sample still has other issues, but it sounds like you're stuck with the existing `CEmployee` base class.

---

An even better solution is to hide as much of the legacy `CEmployee` class as possible; maybe by introducing another class `CEmployeeNew`  (or `CEmployee2`); that might look like:

```
struct CEmployeeNew : public CEmployee
{
    CEmployeeNew(const std::string& name, const std::string& id) :
        CEmployee(const_cast<char*>(name.c_str()), const_cast<char*>(id.c_str())) { }
};
```